# Identify line and charater number in vscode without cursor pointing

Tags: visual-studio-code

We can directly jump to line number and character number in vscode using Ctrl + g
for example 23:7
it will jump to 23rd line and 7th character
how to know character number by just looking screen just like we look line number from left side

I m trying to jump directly to any line any character but character number is unknown

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue for showing column numbers: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/60537. And apparently it was closed. Even if the feature is implemented, it'll be hard for a human to locate the exact column when your target is far from the column number line, and you still need to use arrow keys or your mouse.

As a workaround, you can add multiple rulers in the editor. For example, when you set `"editor.rulers"` to `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]`, you can locate the column approximately by `count(rulers) * 10`, then move your cursor by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> (*Go to the previous/next word*) or <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>. But your editor will end up ugly with these rulers.

In practice, I don't consider column numbers useful. If you can locate the target by them, the target should be on screen right now and the column range is limited. There are so many ways to move the cursor in such a small range.